# Pandas Merge function only giving column headers - Update

Tags: pandas, merge

## What I want to achieve.

I have two data frames. DF1 and DF2. Both are being read from different excel file.
DF1 has 9 columns and 3000 rows, of which one of the column name is "Code Group".
DF2 has 2 columns and 20 rows, of which one of the column name is also "Code Group". In this same dataframe another column "Code Management Method" gives the explanation of code group. For eg. H001 is Treated at recyclable, H002 is Treated as landfill.

## What happens

When I use the command **data = pd.merge(DF1,DF2, on='Code Group')** I only get 10 column names but no rows underneath.

## What I expect

I would want DF1 and DF2 to be merged and wherever Code Group number is same Code Management Method to be pasted for explanation.

## Additional information

```
               Following are datatype for DF1
               Entity                       object
               Address                      object
               State                        object
               Site                         object
               Disposal Facility            object
               Pounds                      float64
               Waste Description            object
               Shipment Date        datetime64[ns]
               Code Group                   object

               FollOwing are datatype for DF2
               Code Management Method    object
               Code Group                object
```

## What I tried

I tried to follow the suggestions from similar post on SO that the datatypes on both sides should be same and Code Group here both are objects so don't know what's the issue. I also tried Concat function.

## Code

```
   import pandas as pd
   from pandas import ExcelWriter
   from pandas import ExcelFile
   CH =  "C:\Python\Waste\Shipment.xls"
   Code = "C:\Python\Waste\Code.xlsx"
   Data = pd.read_excel(Code)
   data1 = pd.read_excel(CH)
   data1.rename(columns={'generator_name':'Entity','generator_address':'Address', 'Site_City':'Site','final_disposal_facility_name':'Disposal Facility', 'wst_dscrpn':'Waste Description', 'drum_wgt':'Pounds', 'wst_dscrpn' : 'Waste Description', 'genrtr_sgntr_dt':'Shipment Date','generator_state': 'State','expected_disposal_management_methodcode':'Code Group'}, 
        inplace=True)
   data2 = data1[['Entity','Address','State','Site','Disposal Facility','Pounds','Waste Description','Shipment Date','Code Group']]
   data2
   merged = data2.merge(Data, on='Code Group')
```

## Getting a Warning

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:5890: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._update_inplace(new_data)

Comment: We can't solve your problem for sure until you provide some data **exhibiting your problem**. In particular, we need a **[mcve]**. You would need to [**edit your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53026827/edit) with this information as text (no images/links).

Comment: still don't get what is your data in `Data`

Comment: Data is just information pertaining to Entity, Address, State, pounds of waste generated. and so on from the excel file. They are all objects.. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Region': [1,2,3],
                    'zipcode':[12345,23456,34567]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ZipCodeLowerBound': [10000,20000,30000],
                    'ZipCodeUpperBound': [19999,29999,39999],
                    'Region': [1,2,3]})

df1.merge(df2, on='Region')
```

this is how the example is given, and the result for this is:

```
   Region   zipcode
0   1       12345
1   2       23456
2   3       34567

   Region   ZipCodeLowerBound   ZipCodeUpperBound
0   1            10000               19999
1   2            20000               29999
2   3            30000               39999
```

and that thing will result in

```
    Region  zipcode ZipCodeLowerBound   ZipCodeUpperBound
0      1      12345       10000             19999
1      2      23456       20000             29999
2      3      34567       30000             39999
```

I hope this is what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

After multiple tries I found that the column had some garbage so used the code below and it worked perfectly. Funny thing is I never encountered the problem on two other data-sets that I imported from excel file.

**data2['Code'] = data2['Code'].str.strip()**